# is there a way in Android to create geo fence proximity alerts without installing an App?

Tags: android

I am looking for ways in which proximity alerts can be configured on the device without having to install an application on the device.

Is that even possible today with Android?

I know that using native code for adding proximity alerts , I can act or send notifications when a device enters a geo fence that is defined by a lat/long and radius.

Comment: Without installing an app? No. You need something that will tell the device to load GPS coordinates and report back to a server **unless** you can somehow acquire data about the phone from the carrier about its location and what cell tower it is currently active on.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is apparently not a programming question, since you are not developing an app, which (by definition) needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

No, Android does not natively support location-based task launching. I do not imagine it will be a part of the OS in the near future either.

For now, you must use apps such as [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) to do this.

If you are looking to incorporate location awareness into your application, take a look at the [Making Your App Location Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html) guide.

Comment: OK thanks that helps a lot. will look at app based development options then.